# How to delete files with specified text in their names?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a folder on my computer in which I have a lot of .jpg files.
I want to filter out all files that have a specific part in their name, for example:

We have a folder which contains files `A.jpg`, `B.jpg`, `C_bad.jpg`, `D_bad.jpg`, etc.

I want to delete every file that has "_bad" in its name. 
Is something like this even possible? Or do I have to delete all these files manually?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### I want to filter out all files that have a specific part in their name

You can do this with [wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html).

---

#### **From a command line**

To display matching files:

```
dir *_bad.jpg
```

To delete matching files:

```
del *_bad.jpg
```

Use the `/s` option to match files in subdirectories as well as the current directory.

---

#### **From Explorer**

To display matching files:

- enter `*_bad.jpg` in the search box

To delete matching files:

- enter `*_bad.jpg` in the search box, select the results and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd>

---

#### Further reading

[wildcards](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)

Comment: Just to add something, if _bad is in the middle of the name just search for *_bad*.jpg otherwise it will only find literally any file ending with _bad.jpg

Answer (score 9):

You can do this easilly using PowerShell :

```
Get-Childitem -path c:\path -Filter *.jpg -Recurse | where-object {$_.Name -ilike "*_bad*"} | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

This little script will delete every JPG files located under **c:\path** (and subfolders), containing "_bad" in their name.

Simply change the root path to match your needs. The **-whatif** parameter used at the end of the script permits to see what files will be deleted. Remove this switch when your are ready to delete them.

Hope this helps !