# How do I delete files with "- copy" in the name using wildcards?

Tags: command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-11, wildcards

I have a problem, which appears that [How to delete files with specified text in their names?](https://superuser.com/q/932515/581166) would delete what I don't want deleted.

Because of an issue with OneDrive after installing an extra internal harddrive and moving my OneDrive folder following the instructions at [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-location-of-your-onedrive-folder-f386fb81-1461-40a7-be2c-712676b2c4ae), I don't know what I did wrong, but now I have all my files copied to my new harddrive and OneDrive is syncing with duplicates of each file with  `- copy` on the end of each file name before the extension.  This is Gigabytes of data over thousands of files.

When looking at what would be deleted if I use `*- copy.*` in Powershell or cmd.exe, it seems that a file I have created (copy.bat) would be deleted, and I want to keep that one.

How would I use wildcards to delete everything with `- copy` on the end of the filename but protect files like copy.bat?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik [yes you can](https://superuser.com/a/1836286/332907)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening at the moment is that your `*- copy.*` is being parsed as two space-separated arguments: `*-` and `copy.*`. Once you see this, it's straightforward to recognise that second of these will match your `copy.bat` file.

The fix is to double-quote the invariant part (specifically, ensuring the space is inside the double-quotes): `*"- copy".*`:

```
DIR *"- copy".*

Get-ChildItem *"- copy".*
```

Since this is Windows, you can actually get away with quoting the `*` too, as it's parsed by the command rather than the Powershell/CMD tool:

```
DIR "*- copy.*"

Get-ChildItem "*- copy.*"
```

As an aside, if you have any intention of using a UNIX/Linux-based system (including a Mac), don't get into the habit of trying to quote a wildcard and expect it to act as a pattern, because it won't: it will get parsed as a literal asterisk. My first suggestion will work everywhere. The second suggestion is Windows-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The `.bat` file doesn't need to be in the same folder as the files
that are being deleted. You may run it from another folder by running
`\path\copy.bat`.

If more files are affected in addition to `copy.bat`, you need to
copy them elsewhere before running `copy.bat`.

You could also in PowerShell use more sophisticated regex expression than
the primitive ones that are available in CMD. You may then refine the
regex to include fewer files, if you can better define their naming rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a useful free tool - Bulk Renaming Utility. https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk

It can recursively scan and preview bulk renaming tasks and is extremely useful as it has a preview. Be warned - You must take a backup first. It's a powerful tool and there isn't any undo option after commit.