What command can be used to delete files, but keep files with specific text in name?
I have many files within D:\cert I want to delete, but also want to keep some files with specific text within the name - how do I remove all *.pdf files, but keep *_sign.pdf and all subfolders?
20241220cert.pdf
20241220cert_sign.pdf
20241221cert.pdf
20241221cert_sign.pdf
20241222cert.pdf
20241222cert_sign.pdf

Example after running script delete:
20241220cert_sign.pdf
20241221cert_sign.pdf
20241222cert_sign.pdf


Can you move the files you want to keep then delete the files that were not moved?

del *cert.pdf?

@echo off

cd /d "d:\cert" || exit /b

for /f usebackq^ ^delims^= %%i in =;(`
    2^>nul where /r . *.pdf ^| findstr /eliv _sign.pdf
    `);= do echo/ del /q /f /a: "%%~dpnxi"

You can test and see the result to check if it meets your expectations. Simply remove the echo/ command, and it will delete the files listed during the test execution.

In PowerShell you can do the same with -whatif:
Remove-Item (ls *.pdf -path d:\Cert -recurse -exclude *_sign.pdf).FullName -whatif


The IF command doesn't understand wildcards for matching. Instead, you need to use substrings to extract the part that you want to match. If you paste the code below into a .CMD or .BAT file, it should do what you’re asking.
@echo off
for /F %%g in ('dir /s /b *.pdf') do call :sub %%g
goto :eof

:sub
set filename=%1
set extension=%filename:~-9%
if [%extension%] NEQ [_sign.pdf] del %filename%
exit /b

I strongly recommend bookmarking ss64.com; it’s an excellent reference for WinBatch, PowerShell, bash on MacOS, and bash on Linux.
While this wasn't too difficult to dope out in WinBatch, my inclination would actually have been to do it in PowerShell, which has better string matching/manipulation and a more capable pipeline, allowing it to be done as a ‘one-liner’:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.pdf | Where-Object {$_.Name -NotLike "*_sign*"} | Remove-Item

Thank you, , Batch file not work but Powershell is worrked for me. Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.pdf | Where-Object {$_.Name -NotLike "*_sign*"} | Remove-Item , and i wil try to use it for autorun.

There is no direct command but you can do it easily by moving the ones you want to save somewhere.  Run this after logging on to the directory where the files are.  I would suggest running one command at a time, to make sure it all works as you expect.
mkdir xtemp
move *_sign.pdf xtemp\
del *.pdf
move xtemp\*.* .
rmdir xtemp

It

Creates a new directory called xtemp
Moves the files to save into this directory
Deletes the unwanted files
Moves the saved files back
Deletes the directory.

Note if something goes wrong in moving from xtemp, rmdir  will not delete the directory as it will not be empty.

Thank you, but i have thousand folders / subfolders, and files....so cannot copy/move one by one... I try this code in CMD: FOR %f IN (*.pdf) DO IF NOT %f==*_sign.pdf DEL /Q %f   but it delete all file. I found this post: [link] (https://superuser.com/questions/932515/how-to-delete-files-with-specified-text-in-their-names) but in my case, i want to keep *_bad.jpg file.

This isn't going to handle recusing through subdirectories well.

Pretty straightforward in powershell. Take off the -whatif to do it for real.
'hi' | set-content file.pdf,file_sign.pdf
mkdir foo2
copy *.pdf foo2
get-childitem -recurse *.pdf -exclude *_sign.pdf | remove-item -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target
  "C:\Users\js\foo\foo2\file.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target
  "C:\Users\js\foo\file.pdf".



Yeah, this was kinda my first thought for a PowerShell solution, but when testing it, I had some anomalous results that I couldn't trace to their source, so I went with the longer and less-efficient version in my answer. This also doesn't handle the recursive aspect, as written.
